# How to pass data between packages in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, package, windowbuilder

I am using Eclipse version Juno. Using WindowBuilder to create a GUI in which the user will enter a number into a JTextField, and then will click a JButton. I have written a for loop to determine whether or not the number entered by the user is a prime number. The GUI window will then display an output along the lines of "The number entered is/is not a prime number" . I am going to have the source code for the GUI written out within one package, while the class with the for loop will be in another package. Both packages reside within the same Java Project.

My question is this: How do I pass the public class containing the loop to the public class containing the GUI source code (so that the GUI can spit out the result of the loop)? Other than that, I don't need any help with writing code. Thanks

This is in response to the first answer:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtNumber;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI window = new GUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 360, 286);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        txtNumber = new JTextField();
        txtNumber.setBounds(134, 13, 182, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtNumber);
        txtNumber.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblPrompt = new JLabel("Enter a number");
        lblPrompt.setBounds(25, 16, 97, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPrompt);

        JButton btnOK = new JButton("OK");
        btnOK.setBounds(208, 196, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnOK);


    }
}

package guiDataProcessing;

public class GUIProcessPrime {
    //A loop that checks whether a number is or is not a prime number
    boolean IsOrIsnotPrime(int num) {
        for(int i=2;2*i<num;i++) {
            if(num%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code - it is hard to help without seeing the context of your code.

Comment: You could pass the "engine"/"for-loop" implementation as part of the constructor or via a "setter" in the GUI.  Make sure you've setup the `import` statements correctly, so that the GUI can see the classes from the other package

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's what I was thinking in the first place.  I am trying to go the way of having a blank JTextArea and only have it display text once the JButton is pressed and loop performs its calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass data between packages, you pass data between objects.  The package structure has very little to do with what you are asking about.  Typically, to pass data between objects, one has to have a reference to the other and the one receiving the data has to have a public method on it for receiving that data.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I'm not particularly adept at programming yet, so the depth of my experience is shallow. I have never been given design guidelines like this before.

Answer (score 0):

For the second class existing in the other package, you must also import the first class for use. The first class would have:

```
package gui;
```

and the second class in the other package would have something like:

```
package gui.otherpackage;
import gui.GUI; //GUI being the name of your first class
```

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented programming data takes the form of object.The data resides in the form of object with some state of instance variables value in heap space of J V M.To identify the address where the object resides in memory we use reference variable in java.So,during programming to use that object we use reference that holds reference to that object.Suppose,if 
A test=new A(); then test points to some memory in heap space with some methods M1...Mn with instances variables values v1....vn of object of class A.So,if you want to pass data between packages then create reference to that object within package level.So,if object has package level hierarchy  like somepackagename.Test.java then create object of  that Test.java and use reference test for operation  .But, that call should be within default,private,protected and public rule to call methods or use instance variables to that object.